# Large loop nest design, anyway to improve speed?

Tags: python, performance, algorithm

I want to loop through a list and check all the possible combinations in it. Currently, I'm using a series of nested for loops, and obviously I'm not ecstatic with the speed using this method. It's very slow and can take 20-30 minutes to go through all the combinations.

```
for n1 in list1:
    list.append(n1)
    for n2 in list2:
        list.append(n2)
        for n3 in list2:
            list.append(n3)
            for n4 in list3:
                list.append(n4)
                for n5 in list3:
                    list.append(n5)
                    for n6 in list4:
                        list.append(n6)
                        for n7 in list4:
                            list.append(n7)
                            for n8 in list5:
                                list.append(n8)
                                for n9 in list5:
                                    list.append(n9)
                                    some logic that determines a value
                                list.remove(n9)
                            list.remove(n8)
                        list.remove(n7)
                    list.remove(n6)
                list.remove(n5)
            list.remove(n4)
        list.remove(n3)
    list.remove(n2)
list.remove(n1)
```

I have no illusions that this is a good way of doing this. I just can't think of a better way of handling this. There ends up being a TON of combos, but I need to calculate the value of each one. There are 5 lists, the combinations I need to check consist of one from list 1, and two spots from list 2-5.

If anyone has suggestions on how to improve this or anyway in python to imrpove the speed of this, that would be appreciated.

The final combination looks something like this:

```
List1[n1], list2[n2], list2[n3], list3[n4], list3[n5], list4[n6], list4[n7], list5[n8], list5[n9].
```

Also, there are combinations where list2 for example could be `list2[0],list2[1]` and `list2[1], list2[0]` which for my purposes are the same thing. Eliminating duplicates like that could reduce my combinations, but I'm unsure of how to approach that.

Comment: have a look at the `itertools` module. It is very helpful

Comment: Yes, sorry. This isn't my code, I just rewrote it to be more brief than the actual code I'm using so it's easier to see.

Comment: You shouldn't call your own variable `list`. And bear in mind that `list.remove` is `O(n)` as you search the whole list (and may get the wrong value if there are duplicates) - `list.pop()` will remove the last value

Comment: Thanks! Duplicates aren't an issue, but simply using list.pop() will probably speed it up and does the exact thing. Very helpful.

Comment: Can you clarify your statement: "combinations I need to check consist of one from list 1, and two spots from list 2-5" ?

Comment: Basically the final combination looks like this: List1, list2, list2, list3, list3, list4, list4, list5, list5.

Comment: Also, there are combinations where list2 for example could be list2[0],list2[1] and list2[1], list2[0] which for my purposes are the same thing. Eliminating duplicates like that could reduce my combinations, but I'm unsure of how to approach that.

Comment: I suggested [a simplification for this in one of your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22405580/1639625). Did this not work?

Comment: Sorry @tobias_k I never saw that. I'm reading it now. Thank you.

Comment: @Tobias_K, I replied to your answer to my other question. Not sure if you'll see it since it's old so I thought I'd mention it here.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you want to cover all combinations of one item picked from `list1`, then two each from `list2` - `list5`. If correct, you can certainly make things more efficient:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations, product

for comb in product(combinations(list1, 1),
                    combinations(list2, 2),
                    combinations(list3, 2), ...):
```

Each `comb` will be in the form `((l1,), (l2, l2), (l3, l3), (l4, l4), (l5, l5))`, but you can flatten this out using `chain.from_iterable`:

```
comb = list(chain.from_iterable(comb))
```

To get `[l1, l2, l2, l3, l3, l4, l4, l5, l5]`.

For a neatness improvement if not actual efficiency, you can define the lists to use and how many items to pick from each up front:

```
lists = [(list1, 1), (list2, 2), (list3, 2), (list4, 2), (list5, 2)]

for comb in product(*(combinations(l, n) for l, n in lists)):
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm now using this code suggested by @tobias_k

```
from itertools import product, combinations
player_combinations = product(combinations(C, 1),
                              combinations(PG, 2),
                              combinations(SG, 2),
                              combinations(PF, 2),
                              combinations(SF, 2))
lineuplist = []
for lineups in player_combinations:
    salary = 0
    names = []
    for players in lineups:
        salary += sum(int(player[2]) for player in players)
    if salarycap - undersalary <= salary <= salarycap:
        for players in lineups:
            names += [player[1] for player in players]
        lineuplist.append(names)
        print(str(names) + " $" + str(salary))
```

Anyone have suggestions for improvements now? Also, does using itertools repeat iterations of PG[0],PG[1] and PG[1], PG[0] reversal combinations like that?